Getting an error with OpenAI integration into my Swift app
I am trying to make an app to provide a trivia question to the users using top 5 medical journal abstracts and the question will be generated using openAI gpt 3.5 turbo. I keep getting an error in the statement:
let chatQuery = ChatQuery(messages: [message], model: "gpt-3.5-turbo") 

which says

Cannot convert value of type 'ChatQuery.ChatCompletionMessageParam?' to expected element type 'Array<ChatQuery.ChatCompletionMessageParam>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'ChatQuery.ChatCompletionMessageParam')

Thank you in advance!
Here is the full code:
class PubMedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var articles: [Article] = []
    @Published var triviaScore: Int = 0
    private var currentTrivia: TriviaQuestion?
    private let openAI: OpenAI

    init() {
        self.openAI = OpenAI(apiToken: "YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY")
        loadTriviaScore()
        generateDailyTrivia()
    }

    func generateDailyTrivia() {
        guard articles.count >= 5 else { return }
        
        let abstracts = articles.prefix(5).map { $0.abstract }.joined(separator: " ")
        let prompt = "Create a trivia question with four options from the following abstracts: \(abstracts)"
        
        Task {
            do {
                let message = ChatQuery.ChatCompletionMessageParam(role: .user, content: prompt)
                let chatQuery = ChatQuery(messages: [message], model: "gpt-3.5-turbo")
                let result = try await openAI.chats(query: chatQuery)
                
                if let triviaContent = result.choices.first?.message.content {
                    // Parse triviaContent to create a TriviaQuestion
                    // Example parsing logic:
                    let question = "What is the main topic?"
                    let options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
                    let correctAnswer = "Option 1"
                    
                    currentTrivia = TriviaQuestion(question: question, options: options, correctAnswer: correctAnswer)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error generating trivia: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    func answerTrivia(with answer: String) {
        if let trivia = currentTrivia, answer == trivia.correctAnswer {
            triviaScore += 1
            saveTriviaScore()
        }
    }

    private func saveTriviaScore() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(triviaScore, forKey: "triviaScore")
    }

    private func loadTriviaScore() {
        triviaScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "triviaScore")
    }
}

I tried using AI itself to help me answer but it keeps going round suggesting "Ensure Non-Optional Initialization: Make sure the ChatQuery.ChatCompletionMessageParam is initialized directly without optionals." which I did but did not fix the problem

It looks like the result returned from ChatQuery.ChatCompletionMessageParam is optional but the function you call after expects an array of not-optional  values. So you need to first unwrap that optional before passing it as an array.
guards let message = ChatQuery.ChatCompletionMessageParam(role: .user, content: prompt) else {
     return 
}
let chatQuery = ChatQuery(messages: [message], model: "gpt-3.5-turbo")

do {
    let result = try await openAI.chats(query: chatQuery)
    //rest of task code

